# Dispatch spec files to jest non-interactively

Tags: jestjs

During development, I run jest for a couple of spec files which are affected. This is how I do it

```
npm run test -- <list of spec file paths>
```

However, this causes jest to startup, execute tests and then stop after the tests complete. Since this happens many times during a day, each execution takes quite a lot of time. What's common across the test runs is the fact jest needs to start and stop, the only changing part is the spec files.

I am wondering if there is an alternative wherein jest could run in the background and I could run a command to inform jest about running test files. I know this sounds like watch mode, but I do not interactive menu on terminal; but a non-interactive way of dispatching spec files to jest.

Once there such a command is available, I would like to run it as below

```
npm run test:dispatch-specs <list of spec file paths>
```